# Problem with lcd - pic interface

Tags: pic, c, lcd, programming

[image]I wrote the following code to display a blinking text on an lcd. The code works properly on the simulator but the real lcd doesn't display anything. I attached the circuit diagram I used to connect the lcd. I would really appreciate it if someone could tell me what did I do wrong.

```
[![// LCD module connections
sbit LCD_RS at PORTD.B2;
sbit LCD_EN at PORTD.B3;
sbit LCD_D4 at PORTD.B4;
sbit LCD_D5 at PORTD.B5;
sbit LCD_D6 at PORTD.B6;
sbit LCD_D7 at PORTD.B7;

sbit LCD_RS_Direction at TRISD.B2;
sbit LCD_EN_Direction at TRISD.B3;
sbit LCD_D4_Direction at TRISD.B4;
sbit LCD_D5_Direction at TRISD.B5;
sbit LCD_D6_Direction at TRISD.B6;
sbit LCD_D7_Direction at TRISD.B7;
// End LCD module connections][1]][1]


char MyFirstText[] = "Hello ";

void main(){
Lcd_Init();                        

  Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_CURSOR_OFF);         
       while(1)
       {
  Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_CLEAR);            
  Lcd_Out(1,6,"Hello ");           
  Lcd_Out(2,6,"World");
  Delay_ms(100);
                  }
  }
```

P.S: I don't have a 10k potentiometer so I connected a 5k instead.

Comment: You forgot to attach the schematic. Also, where do you configure your pins?

Comment: I think that you should put the "LCD_CLEAR" command outside of the loop (i.e. before while(1)) or increase the delay to few seconds.

Comment: @Armandas Sorry, it's attached now.

Comment: @RogerC. I have to keep the `Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_CLEAR); `because I need the text to blink. I could increase the delay though but the things is my lcd doesn't respond at all so I think it might be connection problem.

Comment: When you power up the display (with the PIC idel) you should see 8 character-sized rectangles. If not, adjust the potentiometer, probably all the way to the ground level.

Comment: @Nemo why? As it is now the text won't blink because after the celar you imddediately (re)write the text.

Comment: I don't see anything when I power the display. Can I just connect the 3rd pin directly to ground or vcc instead of the potentiometer ? I think there's something wrong with mine. @WoutervanOoijen

Comment: Where is the rest of your LCD code? (Lcd_Init, Lcd_Cmd, Lcd_Out)

Comment: I'm using MikroC Pro for pic v.6.4.0 so I thought these functions are built in. Do I have to write the body myself ? @brhans

Comment: O.K I'll increase the delay @WoutervanOoijen

Comment: I haven't used MikroC do I don't know for sure, but if you're not getting compile errors then they must be built in... Are there any settings you can configure for those built-in functions? I kinda remember 4-bit parallel LCDs to sometimes be a bit finicky about timing in the initial setup stage.

Comment: O.K the good news is the lcd now works and displays hello world but there's no blinking. I used a 10k fixed resistor to ground instead of the pot. @WoutervanOoijen

Comment: I tried getting the lcd clear outsied the while(1) but still no blinking @brahns

Comment: @Nemo you might use the command LCD_DISPLAYON plus delay followed by LCD_DISPLAYOFF plus delay to produce the blinking effect.

Comment: The schematic looks fishy, where are all the passives? I take it that the MCU has the same voltage levels as the display and built-in pull-down resistors, but that doesn't explain the absence of decoupling caps. You should place the decoupling caps on the same schematic page as the circuits they are used with. There's some old, misguided ideas that all decoupling caps should be placed on the same schematic page as the DC/DC converter: don't do that, it is bad in many ways. It doesn't intuitively tell the person doing the layout that a certain cap needs to be physically close to the IC.

Comment: @Lundin  I'm not really sure I understand you. Are you saying there're missing capacitors ? The only capacitors I used are the two 22pF ones shown in the schematic.

Comment: @Nemo Yes... you need decoupling caps on the supply pins of the MCU and probably on the LCD too.

Comment: @Lundin would you please tell me which capacitor values should I use and on which pins should I connect them both on the lcd and the microchip ?

Answer (score 1):

Now that your LCD works: you see no blinking because you have no delay *while the display is blank*. So it is blank for 0 ms (which you don't notice), then you display the text for 100 ms (which is what you see). Try

```
   while(1){
      Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_CLEAR);            
      Delay_ms( 200 ); // added
      Lcd_Out(1,6,"Hello ");           
      Lcd_Out(2,6,"World");
      Delay_ms( 200 );
 }
```